# create database dynamically in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have some dump files in a folder in which some sql and text files. I want to create database dynamically from user input and uploaded dump files to create tables in it.
I am using dbforge but it is not solving my problem

To create database

```
$this->database->createDatabase($this->input->post('dbName'));

 public function createDatabase($name){
    if ($this->dbforge->create_database($name))
    {
       return true;
    }
}
```

it is creating this database in backend but i dont know how to use it in simple queries in my project.

Comment: see link- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19142625/codeigniter-dynamic-database-connection

Comment: I want to create database on the fly so i can't make specific in database.php