# Re-write or edit database.php configuration file at runtime in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am wondering to edit or update ../config/database.php file at runtime.
For example.

Old database.php file:

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = '111.00.000.00';
$db['default']['username'] = 'username1';
$db['default']['password'] = 'pwd1';
$db['default']['database'] = 'database1';
```

Required or edited database.php should be as:

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = '222.00.000.00';
$db['default']['username'] = 'username2';
$db['default']['password'] = 'pwd2';
$db['default']['database'] = 'database2';
```

But it should must be done at runtime.

Please help me to do this.

I am taking input from user to make default database connection permanently save it in database.php file.

Comment: Refer this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19142625/codeigniter-dynamic-database-connection

Comment: Reference is not Not related! please share some related information.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this link, as in similar way you can edit your `codeigniter's` `database.php` file at runtime.

https://github.com/mikecrittenden/codeigniter-installer/blob/master/index.php

Comment: still unable to edit database.php file. please impart more detail

Comment: Show me what you have tried or atleast edit your question with tried code

Comment: i am not expert as much to do this. so i have only concept and requirement. i am wondering that how to accomplish this requirement!

Comment: Did you tried anything or write any code ? because you will not get your code to be written over here

Comment: Also the link has the code itself, you need to study yourself to get started

Comment: No, actually i just get input of connection string from user and after verification i want to put right information in database.php file. please help me with some sort of code example...

Comment: Yes, you need to take those input's like `hostname`,`username`,`password`,`database_name` and write to the file as shown in the link

Comment: your mentioned link seems helpless in case of codeigniter.

Comment: If you go through the link clearly,it is basically a codeigniter installer example and you need to have a different php folder for setting/configuring CI files.

Comment: is there any other way to attempt this? Actually, i am unable to understand your mentioned link code...

Comment: Did you got the steps, you should follow

Comment: You can share your way to help others